# Pandas pivot_table drops values for aggregate functions that return all None, even if dropna argument is False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, aggregate

The `dropna=False` argument of pandas `pivot_table` is not doing what I expect it to do. I'm starting with the following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
# pd.__version__ = '0.23.3'

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit':['apple','orange','peach','apple','peach'], 
    'size': [1,1.5,1,2,1],
    'taste': [7,8,6,6,10]})
```

...and the following aggregate functions:

```py
def return_one(x): 
    return 1

def return_sum(x):
    return sum(x)

def return_none(x):
    return None
```

I would like to reshape `df` so that the:

- index is made up of the original column names ('size','taste').
- values are the result of the aggregate functions applied to values within a group.
- columns are the fruit types ('apple', 'orange', 'peach')

The following `pivot_table` is almost there:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, columns='fruit', 
               aggfunc=[return_sum,return_none,return_one], 
               dropna=False)
```

[image: values returned by return_none have been dropped]

*Except that* the output of `return_none` has been dropped. I would expect the pivoted table to include a set of empty cells for the `return_none` function because `dropna=False`, but it does not. Can anyone suggest how to include the output of `return_none`?

Comment: `return None` is working as it should. What do you want returned? `np.nan` an empty string

Comment: Thanks @Chris 3. I would like the value 'None' to be displayed within cells, in the same way as "1" appears for `return_one`.

Comment: Just `'None'` as a string?

Comment: if the above is the case just change `return None` to `return 'None'`

Comment: The issue is that I have many aggregate functions, some of which sometimes return entirely `None` or `np.nan`. I still need the dataframe to be populated, even if the returned values are `None/np.nan`. The functions aren't returning a string, and it would be a fudge to try to make them return one.

Comment: @tomp I am really surprised that the dropna keyword is ignored. pivot_table assigns NaN or None values from the agg functions, but removes columns where all values are NA despite the dropna parameter. That looks buggy to me - or at least this is not a behavior I would expect.

Comment: Raised as an issue at: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was raised on the [pandas repository](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22159) and [the fix was implemented in April 2019](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25738).
In current versions of Pandas, the `pivot_table` `Dropna` argument is respected when it is False:

```
import pandas as pd
# pd.__version__ is '1.5.0'

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple','orange','peach','apple','peach'], 
    'size': [1, 1.5, 1, 2, 1],
    'taste': [7, 8, 6, 6, 10]})

def return_one(x): 
    return 1

def return_sum(x):
    return sum(x)

def return_none(x):
    return None 

pd.pivot_table(df, columns='fruit', 
               aggfunc=[return_sum, return_none, return_one], 
               dropna=False)
```

Returns:

```
      return_sum              return_none              return_one             
fruit      apple orange peach       apple orange peach      apple orange peach
size         3.0    1.5   2.0        None   None  None          1      1     1
taste       13.0    8.0  16.0        None   None  None          1      1     1
```